# Unable to add a Junit file in eclispe

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have an eclipse java project (screen shots attached). I added Junit libraries to my project and when I say New file, I don't see Junit option.

Once Junit libraries are added, eclipse should be able to show the Junit files. Not sure why it wouldn't

[image: No Junit option]

Answer (score 0):

You can install it by the following:

```
Help -> Install New Software
```

within Eclipse. In the Work with: field, your Eclipse version should have a Site entry in the dropdown, such as:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201406250900

Once you choose this, you can then navigate to:

```
Programming Languages -> Eclipse Java Development Tools
```

It should then appear afterwards

Comment: Harmenx, I did what you asked me. It restarted eclipse. I stil don't see JUnit.  thank you for your reply.